# Showing that the excluded point topology is first-countable

Tags: general-topology

I'm new to topology and so I'm questioning myself here. But, this is what I've got:

We have $\tau_p = \{ U \subseteq X : p \notin U \} \cup \{X\}$. Let $x \in X$ such that $x \neq p$. Then,
$X^{\circ} = X$, $\emptyset^{\circ} = \emptyset$, $\{p\}^{\circ} = \emptyset$, $\{x\}^{\circ} = \{x\}$.

Hence, the only neighborhood of $p$ is $X$, and the only neighborhood of $x$ is $\{x\}$. So, the neighborhood bases are given by $\mathcal{U}_p = \{X\}$ and $\mathcal{U}_x = \{\{x\}\}$. These are both countable and so $(X, \tau_p)$ is first countable.

So, have I done this right?

Comment: I think your question may have several typos. First, I think it should be $\tau_p = Y \cup \{X\}$. Second, $Y$ is not a subset of $X$, so it doesn't make sense to write $Y^\circ$.

Comment: @Sambo That's true, I guess I was worried that I wasn't including something and so I also added that, but I can see how it is meaningless.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix these typos. Assuming I'm understanding correctly, your neighborhood bases seem correct, and it gives you the correct conclusion, but the justification for the bases is shaky. Go back to the definition and try to work from there.

Comment: @Sambo could you elaborate on how the justification is shaky? I have just followed the definitions I've been given in lectures.

Comment: The accepted answer is great. I'll add one thing: you said that the only neighborhood of $x$ is $\{x\}$, which is incorrect. Any subset containing $x$ and not containing $p$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, some of the statements you made do not make sense. But you have the right idea. We could write something like the following.

Consider $X$ in the topology $\mathcal{T}_p$ consisting of $X$ along with all subsets of $X$ that do not contain the point $p \in X$. Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary.

1. If $x = p$, then the only neighborhood of $x$ is the entire $X$. So, a countable basis for $p$ is just $\{X\}$.
2. If $x \ne p$, then the singleton $\{x\}$ is open, since it does not contain $p$. Any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ must contain $x$, so it follows that $\{x\} \subseteq U$. Therefore, $\{\{x\}\}$ constitutes a countable basis for $x$.